# Send Push notification from user app to admin app - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I have two flutter apps 1- user app and 2- admin app. User wants to send request to admin using push notification. I have implemented firebase push notification using rest API, but it works only within app using device token. Is there any way to send notifications to different apps with different package names? I am sending device to device notifications not to all users or admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can you need to register different apps in the firebase console and do configuration just like you did for the current app i.e configure google_play_services.json etc

Comment: should i have to add both google json files into both user and admin projects?

Comment: use same firebase projects and add multiple apps